# SQLite EF6 Struct in Entity Framework Model Efficiency

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to have an object called `CityObject` in my application that is currently organised in a way where each group of integers is categorized into it's own struct inside of the `CityObject`, the variables are accessed by directory then variable to reference them easily.

Here is the `CityObject` class:

```
public class CityObject
{
    public struct Harvest { public int wood, stone, coal, iron, water, food; public int all() { return wood + stone + coal + iron + water + food; } }
    public Harvest harvest = new Harvest();

    public struct Production { public int steel, copper, gold, electricity; public int all() { return steel+copper+gold+electricity; } }
    public Production production = new Production();

    public struct Invention { public int medicine, electronic, motors; public int all() { return medicine+electronic+motors; } }
    public Invention invention = new Invention();

    public struct Structures { public int housing, barracks, laboratory, defense; public int all() { return housing+barracks+laboratory+defense; } }
    public Structures structures = new Structures();
}
```

However, when using objects as data models for EF6 they are usually in a strict manner:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway I can maintain my usage of my more advanced `CityObject` when using an SQLite database? I have created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Cities` 
(
    `User`  TEXT,
    `wood`  INTEGER,
    `stone` INTEGER,
    `coal`  INTEGER,
    `iron`  INTEGER,
    `water` INTEGER,
    `food`  INTEGER,
    `steel` INTEGER,
    `copper` INTEGER,
    `gold` INTEGER,
    `electricity`   INTEGER,
    `medicine`  INTEGER,
    `electronic`    INTEGER,
    `motors`    INTEGER,
    `housing`   INTEGER,
    `barracks`  INTEGER,
    `laboratory`    INTEGER,
    `defense`   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`User`)
);
```

I am hoping there is a pretty direct way to use that table with that object, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Each user can have only one city. Is that correct?

Comment: no, user is primary key, users can have more than one

Comment: You can use eventually EF Complex Types for that, but the structs must be converted to classes and fields to properties, thus increasing the memory usage and GC pressure.

Comment: When the primary key of Cities is user then you can have one city for one user. If you do not want that your table design is wrong

Comment: So cities should just have an id?

Comment: Should I just reference each variable within the cityobject domain? harvestWood harvestIron?